# Why can't `ranges::begin` be called on a `const any_view`?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, range-v3

I have this code that fails ([Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hzqYGTh4j)):

```
#include <range/v3/view/any_view.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> a{1};

   const ranges::any_view<int, ranges::category::forward> av(a);
   ranges::begin(av);
}
```

And was in the impression that `begin` returns a new iterator into the range, that allows me to iterate through it several times. Why would it need a modifiable range for that?

As reference (but I'm more interested in the reason of the above than (just) a solution to my problem below), in my real code, this appears as

```
void merge(ranges::any_view<int, ranges::category::forward> av) {
   for(auto x : av) { ... }
}
```

And unfortunately `clang-tidy` warns that `av` should be made `const&` because it's passed by value but not moved inside of the function body.

---

My suspicion is that it has to do with the "amortized constant time complexity" requirement of `begin` / `end` calls. The following fails because I think the `begin` iterator can't be cached in the `const` view returned by `drop`:

```
std::list<int> b{1, 2, 3, 4};

const auto latter = ranges::views::all(b) | ranges::views::drop(2);
ranges::begin(latter);
```

So just in case the type-erased variable contains such a view, it has to cache the first result of `begin` for all wrapped types. However, even if I change `av` to `random_access`, it won't let me call `begin` on a `const any_view`:

```
const ranges::any_view<int, ranges::category::random_access> av(a);
```

And if this is indeed the reason why it fails for `input`, I wonder whether there's a way around this? Like the `std::move_only_function` allows a moving `std::function` (kind of) in C++23.

Comment: Add `const` for value types instead of `any_view` eg. `ranges::any_view<const int, ranges::category::forward>`?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any good reason for this. `any_view` is [implemented](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/9aa41d6b8ded2cf5e8007e66a0efd1ab33dbf9a5/include/range/v3/view/any_view.hpp#L600-L609) as holding a `unique_ptr` to an interface, which `begin_cursor()` just dereferences. So just... marking `begin_cursor()` and `end_cursor` `const` just works.

Comment: PRs welcome :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd call this very much a clang-tidy defect. It shouldn't complain about your passing `any_view<T>` by value; nor `string_view`; nor `span<T>`; nor `function_ref<Sig>`; nor any other type-erased view-semantic type. The *entire point* of these types is that you pass them by value.

(Likewise, I would hope that clang-tidy doesn't complain about passing `unique_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<T>` by value. In those cases, the reason to pass the type at all is to *participate in lifetime*, and if you take by `const&` you're failing to participate in lifetime, which can cause awful bugs in a multithreaded program. Vice versa, if you don't need to participate in lifetime you should take `const T&` or `const T*`, not `const unique_ptr<T>&`.)

Okay, so, @Barry says "PRs welcome [on `any_view`, I'm going to assume]." I'm not 100% sure, but I *think* that would be a bad idea. Iterating a view in C++20-Ranges-world is a mutating operation by definition. `any_view` type-erases over that operation. Thus iterating an `any_view` is a mutating operation by definition. Sure, one could *physically* slap a `const` qualifier on `any_view::begin`, but that would be a *semantic* mistake, just like it was when C++11 did it for `std::function::operator()`.

Here's what `std::function` does wrong:

```
auto lam = [i=0]() mutable { return ++i; };
std::function<int()> f = std::move(lam);
auto worker = [](const std::function<int()>& f) {
  f();  // OK, const operation is presumed thread-safe
};
auto t1 = std::jthread(worker, std::cref(f));
auto t2 = std::jthread(worker, std::cref(f));
  // and boom goes the dynamite
```

Both `t1` and `t2` will try to modify `f`'s controlled lambda's capture `i` at the same time. This is UB.

Now here's how `any_view` would go wrong *if* it were const-iterable:

```
auto r = std::views::filter(std::views::iota(1), isOdd);
std::any_view<int> v = std::move(r);
auto worker = [](const std::any_view<int>& v) {
  v.begin();  // OK, const operation is presumed thread-safe
};
auto t1 = std::jthread(worker, std::cref(v));
auto t2 = std::jthread(worker, std::cref(v));
  // and boom goes the dynamite
```

Both `t1` and `t2` will try to modify `v`'s controlled `filter_view`'s [cache](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.view#5) at the same time. This is UB.

---

`std::move_only_function` and `std::function_ref` (and soon [`std::copyable_function`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2548r6.pdf) IIUC) deal with this problem by providing different signatures for callability versus const-callability.

```
auto lam = [i=0]() mutable { return ++i; };
std::copyable_function<int()> f = std::move(lam);  // OK
auto worker = [](const std::copyable_function<int()>& f) {
  f();  // error, can't use the mutable operator() on a const f
};

auto lam = [i=0]() mutable { return ++i; };
std::copyable_function<int() const> f = std::move(lam);
  // error, can't store a mutable lam in a copyable_function<int() const>
auto worker = [](const std::copyable_function<int() const>& f) {
  f();  // OK
};
```

There's no natural place to hang the `const` on `any_view`'s template parameter; but I could imagine a library providing both `lib::any_view<T>` and `lib::const_any_view<T>`, if there were really any demand for the latter.

As I said first of all, though, I don't think there should *be* any demand for the latter. The only reason you were trying to do `const any_view&` at all is because clang-tidy told you to; and that's clearly just a bug in clang-tidy.

Comment: Thanks, this is very enlightening. IIRC if a range is borrowable, its state is stored in the iterators, right? Are those the ones that are const-iterable?

Comment: Because any_view is eypensivezto copy, like boost::any, I wanted to avoid copies. I sort of disagree with "the entire point of them is to pass them by value". Their point is to be non-owning, and of some of them to pass them by value. But the byvalue passing is not an intrinsic property of non-ownership. It is because some of them are cheap to copy. In fact I would agree the non-ownering makes it plausible to use passbyref where appropriate, _because_ keeping a separate lifetime-extender is not a concern there.

Comment: I also have another question! Why is begin's caching considered a modification even though it doesn't change the result? Is it not more appropriate to make the cache member mutable and the begin function const?

Comment: NVM I came to understand that the std views are a huge mess and I certainly won't use them and likely neither ranges-v3. Belleviews looks good but I'm not sure whether it will survive.

Comment: "if a range is borrowable, its state is stored in the iterators" — Yes, a borrowed range is "boneless" — "deboning" it into an iterator/sentinel pair is totally safe. So any state it has, must be stored in the iterator/sentinel. "Are those the ones that are const-iterable" — As usual in C++, you're philosophically correct but technically there are more wrinkles. Suppose the iterator type is non-copyable; then you might not be able to extract it with `begin() const`. E.g. `subrange<istream_view::iterator>` is `borrowed_range` but still not const-iterable. https://godbolt.org/z/r9T6xsjGj