# How does ranges::any_view work and how is it behaving in conjunction to cache1 in these cases?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, range-v3, c++23

##### tl;dr

It's not clear to me how `ranges::any_view<T, C>` works, especially in relation to what `T` is, i.e. a `&`, a `const&`, a value type, or what else.¹

##### Research

[There isn't really much about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%5Brange-v3%5D+%22any_view%22), yet, nor I have found much around, beside [this very useful explanation of why `ranges::begin` can't be called on `const ranges::any_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76885439/5825294).

##### A tricky (?) case

[Here's one such example which puzzles me a lot](https://godbolt.org/z/MTrcz94ar), and below are the relavants bit of it. I think that thoroughly understanding why the examples linked below work (or don't) the way they do, should help me understand what `any_view` actually is.

This function accepts any range of `std::string`s and `print`s each of them (the `filter(always(true))` is letting everything pass):

```cpp
void test(any_view<std::string> parts) {
    for_each(parts | filter(always(true)), print);
};
```

Now, if I pass an lvalue of type `any_view<std::string const&>`

```cpp
any_view<std::string const&> view{foos};
```

into it,

```cpp
test(view);
```

all is fine, but if I first pipe that into `cache1`²,

```cpp
test(view | cache1);
```

then the all the `std::string`s result empty.

By trial and error I realized that changing

```cpp
test(any_view<std::string> parts) {
```

to

```cpp
test(any_view<std::string const&> parts) {
```

[solves the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/xYhM4v55z), but I don't really understand why.

But if I then was to also change

```cpp
any_view<std::string const&> view{foos};
```

to

```cpp
any_view<std::string> view{foos};
```

[then I'd get a SIGSEGV](https://godbolt.org/z/fv4fGnn3n).

Furthermore, [manually inlining the body of `test` at the call site, also seems to solve the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/fEnjYcas1).

And to make the thing trickier, when I try to change `std::string` for a `Foo` that holds a `std::string` (and sets it to `""` in the destructor, to hopefully make possible UB a bit more "observable"), [the issue seems to go away](https://godbolt.org/z/873KMhPda).

##### Side question

I know there's no `any_view` in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), and I guess there won't be one in [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) either, but is there a reason ([beside performance](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/714)) why it's not been included yet or won't be included in the foreseeable future? I mean, to me it looks like it does serve a ligitimate purpose, so what else in the standard library is or will fill that hole?

---

(¹) It's a bit clearer what the role of `C` is, especially because I had an experience of downgrading an `any_view<SomeType, sized>` to `any_view<SomeType, forward>` for the purpose of allowing storing a `filter_view`, which is not sized, into it.

(²) Yes, the `cache1` is useless here, but in my real usecase I had `view | transform(f) | filter(g)`, so I inserted `cache1` in between [to prevent `f` from being called twice for each entry `x` in `view` which passes the test `g(f(x))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199729/5825294).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of a few things:

1. For `any_view<T>`, the `reference` type of the range is `T`. `any_view<string>` is a range of prvalue `string`, while `any_view<string const&>` is a range of lvalues of `string const`.
2. `any_view<T>` accepts any range who reference is *convertible* to `T`, not *same as* `T`. So you can construct an `any_view<string>` from a range whose reference type isn't just `string` or even `char const*` but also, relevantly here, `string&&`.
3. The way `cache1` is implemented in range-v3 is probably not the best way to do this, and looks like:

   ```cpp
   range_value_t<Rng>&& read() const {
       if (parent_->dirty_) { /* update cache */ }
       return std::move(*parent_->cache_);
   }
   ```
4. `filter` requires dereferencing iterators more than once (once to see if it passes the filter, and then the second time for when you actually use the value).

So when you do this:

```cpp
vector<string> foos = {...};
any_view<string> parts = foos | cache1;
```

`foos | cache1` is a range of `string&&` (which is an xvalue into `cache1`'s internal cache, `foos` is unaffected - it could've been `const` too). We're converting that to `any_view<string>`, which is now a range of `string`, which means that somewhere in all these types we have an iterator whose `operator*()` returns a `string` from the result of dereferencing `(foos | cache1)`'s iterator. That will *move from* `cache1`'s cache. So if you dereference twice, you will end up with an empty cache.

Then when you do `parts | views::filter(pred)`, because you dereference every iterator twice (once to check if it satisfies the predicate, the second to print it), you will end up moving from the cached `string` right before you print it, so you only get empty strings.

---

The problem here is probably that `cache1` is a range of `range_value_t<V>&&`, which can lend itself to this double-dereference issue. If it were a range of `range_value_t<V>&` instead, then this would just work (at the cost of every dereference of your `any_view<string>` leading to a `string` copy). On the other hand, if you *won't* dereference the iterator more than once, you *do* want to just move, since if you were doing something like:

```cpp
some | pipeline | cache1 | to<std::vector>();
```

You don't want to have to remember to write:

```cpp
some | pipeline | cache1 | as_rvalue | to<std::vector>();
```

---

Note that a similar problem exists for `views::concat(r1, r2)` if `r1` is a range of `string` and `r2` is a range of `string&&`, you will end up with a range whose reference type is `string`, such that dereferencing that iterator will end up *moving from* the elements of `r2`. Which is what you want to happen if you're doing `views::concat(r1, r2) | to<vector>()`, but is definitely want you don't want to happen if you're doing `views::concat(r1, r2) | filter(p) | ...`

It's hard to know what the right answer is.